# Playframwork 2.x trying to generate custom 400 response

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

Trying to generate a custom 400 response. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to send a 204 in place of a 400 response in my global settings. Please let me know if you cna help me out.

Thanks

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

   @Override
   public Promise<Result> onBadRequest(RequestHeader request, String error){
     return status(204); //ideally but don't know what to put here
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {


@Override
public Promise<Result> onError(RequestHeader arg0, Throwable arg1) {
    super.onError(arg0, arg1);
    return F.Promise.promise(()->{return play.mvc.Results.noContent();});
}

@Override
public Promise<Result> onBadRequest(RequestHeader arg0, String arg1) {
     super.onBadRequest(arg0, arg1);
    return F.Promise.promise(()->{return play.mvc.Results.noContent();});
}


}
```

In your application.conf

```
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
application.global=Global
```

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't returning promises which is what got me. The docs seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public play.mvc.Result onBadRequest(RequestHeader request, String error) {        
        return play.mvc.Results.noContent(); //Generates a 204 NO_CONTENT simple result
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html#noContent())

Comment: System error. noContent() is not the correct return type :(